# AWS SSO with AWS CLI - python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I am a beginner learning AWSCLI, and boto3 with Python. I am trying to execute a few operations using Python boto3 on my s3 bucket. For running the code, I had to copy-paste the short-lived credentials often into my terminal/command prompt (I am a federated user for an organization AWS account). Is there a way to configure the creds so I don't have to do the copy-paste every time?

Something I tried: I did `aws configure sso`. The profile seems correct at `~/.aws/config`. But when I run the Python code, it errors that `botocore.expceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

Any guidance or direction would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you log in with `aws login`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I did `aws sso login` in the terminal after setting up the `aws configure sso`. Also, to add more context -> when I do `aws s3 ls --profile profile_name` in the terminal, it works. It lists all the s3 buckets but the python file execution throws error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it, not sure if this is the best approach. Posting here for reference or for someone to correct me, so I added a new line to the code before creating the s3 client to retrieve the local profile:

`boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='configured profile name')`

Comment: Yes, if your configuration is in a 'profile', then you will need to tell boto3 which profile to use. Good work!